# Height of overflow-hidden item in flex item in absolute flexbox container

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have following simple HTML snippet which has different result in Chrome and Safari

```
<body>
  <div id="1" style="position: absolute; display: flex; flex-direction: column; /* height: 78px; */">
    <div id="2" style="height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
      <div id="3" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
        <p><span>CSS</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The content is shown perfectly in Chrome while in Safari, `#3` height is `0`.

If I do one of following

- Set an explicit height to `#1`
- Remove `height: 100%` on `#2`
- Remove `overflow:hidden` on `#3`
- remove `disaplay:flex` on `#1` or `#2`

The height of all elements are calculated correctly in Safari. It's likely a problem with Safari's Flexbox but not sure what's the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

If `#2` is a flex container in column direction, then `#3` is a flex item with a vertical inline axis. To get `#3` to take the full height of the parent – in browsers where it doesn't happen automatically – just give `#3` this rule: `flex: 1` or `height: 100%`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried the two rules you mentioned on `#3` but they didn't work in Safari.

Comment: I read quite a few of your answers about Flexbox and actually looked forward to your answer before you replied :) `#2` is set as `height:100%` which relies on `#1`'s height, while `#1` is absolutely positioned and has no `height` set, I suppose `#1` would try to use content height, am I right?

Comment: Browser behavior can vary. It's always safer to specify a height on the parent when using a percentage height on the child. https://jsfiddle.net/3jtr3h9e/

Comment: `#3` is `overflow:hidden` then it tries to crop the content per height and width of parent block, which is `#2`. However `#2`'s height is decided by `#1` but `#1`'s height is still unknown. That's how I see the problem but I still don't understand why `display:flex` can affect the behavior. Anyway you are right percentage is not safe, thanks!

Comment: If you want to post a more clear and detailed demo, I'll look at it again.